# Store Checkbox items into database

Tags: android, web-services, android-listview, checkbox, ksoap

I have an Android application that displays a list of names using checkboxes. I want to store the checked items and the unchecked items in my databases . I don't want to store any data item permanently on the phone. I require a mechanism by which I can store the data (checked and unchecked) temporarily on the phone and then transfer it to database via a web service.

Can anyone tell me how to go about doing this ? What modifications should I do to my current code?

Here is my Android code that displays the list :

```
      package com.demo;

      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
      import java.net.SocketException;
      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import java.util.List;
      import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.app.AlertDialog;
      import an droid.content.DialogInterface;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.util.Log;
      import android.widget.TextView;
      import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity; 
      import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
      import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
      import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
      import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
      import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
      import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
      import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
      import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
      import org.json.JSONArray;
      import org.json.JSONException;
      import org.json.JSONObject;
      import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
      import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
      import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
      import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
      import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;



 public class TestApp extends Activity {

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/getData";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getData";

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/getdata2/Service1.asmx";
    TextView tv;

boolean[] bln1=null; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

           String[] arr2= call();


           boolean[] bln=new boolean[arr2.length];
    for(int i=0;i<arr2.length;i++)
   {  
        bln[i]=false;

    }  

   bln1 = new boolean[arr2.length];

    new AlertDialog.Builder(TestApp.this)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setMultiChoiceItems(arr2,
            bln,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton,
                        boolean isChecked) {

                                        if(isChecked){
                                    bln1[whichButton] = true;
                                           }
                    else{
                        bln1[whichButton] = false;
                    }
                }
            })
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            String[] arr2=call();
            for(int i=0;i<arr2.length;i++)
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("key"+i,arr2[i]);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            JSONArray jArrayParam = new JSONArray();
            jArrayParam.put(jsonObject);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bulkdata",
                    jArrayParam.toString()));

            Log.e("bulkdata", jArrayParam.toString());

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/login2/Service1.asmx");//web service to send data to to forward to database

        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair,  HTTP.UTF_8));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Execute HTTP Post Request

        try {
            HttpResponse response=null;
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.e("entity:",entity.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // get response entity

        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


        }
    })
   .show();


}


public String[] call()
{
    SoapPrimitive responsesData = null; 

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope( 
    SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
    envelope.dotNet = true; 
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.debug = true; 

    try {

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    responsesData = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse(); 
    System.out.println(" --- response ---- " + responsesData); 

    } catch (SocketException ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    System.out.println( " ----" + responsesData );

    String serviceResponse= responsesData .toString(); 


    String[] temp; 
    String delimiter = "#"; 
    temp= serviceResponse.split(delimiter);
    System.out.println( " ---- length ---- " + temp.length); 

    return temp; 

                }

         }
```

[image: My output till now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the error is in the .setPositiveButton() method, in the line String[] arr2=call().

Why are you reading again data from your webservice, like you did in the onCreate method, and putting it the the json result?

Shouldn't you put in json result checkbox status, instead of original data?

Comment: There is no error in the code ..it works fine .. I just want to make an improvement to it by storing the checked and unchecked items into a database via some mechanism...ignore the second HttpPost ...I have not really used it and yes it should be removed and will do that..thanks a lot !! :D

Comment: Ah ok ;)
What about using SharedPreferences to store your checkbox results and retrieve them when you want to send them? At the end of app lifecycle, reset the preferences. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: I will be having say 70-80 entries when my database is complete.. So is there any size restriction as such for SharedPreferences ? and i have to use SharedPreferences within both my methods of .setPositive and .setNegative right ?

Comment: Basically, SharedPreferences is an xml file parsed by the system, so no problem to add 80 or more fields to it.

.SetPositive and .SetNegative refer to Ok on Cancel button event, not to pression of a single checkbox inside the dialog. Please refer to official documentation in order to understand how to manage dialog with a list (quick question, in OnMultiChoiceClickListener event): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList